# How to add TypeScript Interface to shorthand variable?

Tags: node.js, typescript, request

How to set TypeScript interface to variable looking like this:

```
const { body, statusCode } = await got.post('smth', requestOpts)
```

How can I set the interface to ex. `body`. I would like to assign there an interface with potential requests from the server. An interface that I'm willing to implement looks like that:

```
    interface ResponseBody {
        data: [{ username: string }]
    }
```

I tried different things to attach this interface to the upper variable `body` but I'm getting build errors. The only workaround that I have here is to do not use shorthand variable but that's not my goal - I wonder if there are solutions for such issue.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcwjANHA3geTDYEB2AzpgGYBSAypgHIBKApoZEfQEIQAmAngL5wlQIIOAHIkMEQChQkWHADGAQ0IBXRQBt+g4SKWqNUyfIKF4UegEcVjGNhiEAXHDt4ipSjQZMTbTlzgAvBiSAJBg5iTAAB4AqlDqTiIAFjAwYA4A9BnqEErqSRCmIiihAFaEBE7ooSEqhPRQ+Iog9E56auoAdHUNTS0lITwlPJLS+DANJIry9HBezPXs3MEhHIowik4A2uhwPY3NrXCmUMD4CHA8ALqSI5JZcACScADuECrqHHDqwADWszAIHB1ht5Ek4GcJlApjM4IC4AADABGfgRcAAbopTookep6EYTPBdijuGhTOs6gBhTizPhBRQvRTAeDiTqQUwAChE+0IxTg5isNjshAAlJIgA)

Comment: Hmm, what interface are you talking about?  Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/Ndj30W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Okay, I'll update my question.

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7PgBm) meet your needs?  The answer as asked is to annotate the whole object like `{body, statusCode} : {body: ResponseBody, statusCode: number}`.  But apparently `got` lets you just specify `post` with a type parameter like `post<ResponseBody>(...)`, which is probably what you *should* do... despite the fact that your question is not asking about this.

Comment: `post<ResponseBody>(…)` is the exact thing for which I was looking for! Thanks for your help - you can add this comment as an answer because that's the solution.

Comment: I'm happy to write up an answer but can you [edit] your question so that it's specific to `got` then?  Right now you've got an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It wasn't really specific to `got`, I was struggling with these shorthands and I was avoiding them at some point because I had no idea how to attach interfaces to them and your answer helped me with this issue. But the method to attach interface to `post()` method is way more efficient than attaching interfaces to variables.

Comment: Then the answer will be `{body, statusCode} : {body: ResponseBody, statusCode: number}` (with a link to [ms/TS#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526) which asks for a nicer way to do it), and I'll only mention `post<ResponseBody>(...)` as an aside, because it doesn't directly address the question as asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) the whole object, like this:

```
const { body, statusCode }: { body: ResponseBody, statusCode: number } =
    await got.post<ResponseBody>('users', requestOpts)
```

While it would be nice if you could annotate the individual [destructured variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) inside the object, this is not currently possible.  The syntax `const { body: ResponseBody } = ...` can't work because JavaScript interprets this as [assigning to a new variable name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names) (so there'd be a variable named `ResponseBody` holding the value that was in the `body` property).  Perhaps something like `const { body::ResponseBody, statusCode::number }` would work instead, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#29526](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29526).  But for now this is not possible, and you have to annotate the whole object.

---

That's the answer to the question as asked.

Do note that for your particular example, though, the [`got.post()` method has a call signature](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/b29eb54401d4f9157a53d3141d2266b31089ced9/source/types.ts#L145) that's [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type you expect the `body` property to be.  So you can write

```
const { body, statusCode } = await got.post<ResponseBody>('users', requestOpts);
```

to get a strongly typed `body` variable with a minimum of extra keystrokes.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAcwjANHA3nA8mGwIB2AzlgGYBSAylgHIBKApkZMQwEIQAmAnnAL5xSUCCDgByJDDEAoUJFhwAxgEMiAV2UAbQcNFiV6rTOmLCReFAYBHNUxg4YRAFzZc+YmSq1GzM+y68ALwY0gCQYJakwAAeAKpQmi5iABYwMGBOAPSZmhAqmskQ5mIoYQBWRIQu6GGhakQMUATKIAwuBhqaAHT1jc2tpaF8pXzSsgQwjaTKigxwPiwNHDwhoZzKMMouANqYvU0tbXDmUMAECPwAutKjY6rcBIqCao94hHAMwDDJjQAUAJSrUzEeCYABGATQ5g29QAwlw5gJgsoAO7KL6IZBdSDmAA8Cz8y24AD5fmJ9kQSnBLDY7A4iP8ANxjW73R7PV7uODQAFAsyguAQnhQzYwOEI-jVQUBFwE1hEkUwojwzhHAhqEBgxr8OCBWqo9HwSTYoowfFMRb+Hik8kNKCUtA02zmen-G5jaRAA)

Comment: That is, the best solution has nothing to do with destructuring, just actually using the API with type safety as designed.